# How to discover PsyStarcraft's build orders?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, sc2-build-order

I am looking for PsyStarcraft's favorite/most common build order(s). I'm a bronze-level and I find it hard to obtain just from YouTube replays (even when he says what's going on :). I'm especially interested in the following replays:

LIVE Rapz[P] vs [Z]vilePsY

SC2 LMntStallion[T] vs [Z]vilePsY

SC2 akrhRH[Z] vs [Z]vilePsY

How can I tell what exact build orders is he using?

Comment: I'm worried this may be too localized, since pro players tend to switch up their build orders. Perhaps if you provided a few videos and asked for those build ordrs, or, better yet, asked a question on how you can tell what Build order someone is using?

Comment: Are you able to get your hands on the replay files used in the videos?

Comment: @Sorean I'm afraid I'm not :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Game 1: Live game (no production tab), I'll do the best I can.

- 11 Pool
- 15 Extractor
- 16 Overlord
- 16 Queen
- 18 4 lings
- 21 Hatch
- 23 Overlord
- 26 Queen
- 30 Overlord
- 34 Drone transfer (Nothing else was going on)
- 42 Hatchery
- 43 Macro Hatchery
- 48 3 Extractors
- 49 2 Overlords
- 59 8 Lings
- 60 Lair
- 60 Evolution Chamber
- 61 Metabolic Boost
- 76 Roach Warren
  At this point he just started massing lings to counter all the zealots that were coming.
- 68 Evolution Chamber
  Run by as soon as ling speed finished.
  Roaches made as soon as roach warren finished.

Game 2:

- 15 Hatch
- 16 Pool
- 18 Overlord (He supply capped himself :P)
- 18 Extractor
- 18 2x Queen 4 lings
- 25 Overlord
- 26 Spine crawler
- 26 Overlord
- 30 Ling speed
- 31 Overlord
- 31 Evolution Chamber (Side note, he could have built the evo chamber under the spine to force the hellions to have to run around the spine. In other words, he could have used the evolution chamber as part of a wall.)
- 35 Roach Warren (He mentions that it is late).
- 35 8x lings
  Can't really get the build order after this point since he's losing units and reacting.

Game 3:

- 15 Hatch
- 16 Pool
- 17 Extractor
- 17 Overlord
- Soon as the overlord finishes
- 18 2x Queen 4 lings
- 26 Spine crawler
- 26 Overlord
- 28 Roach Warren
- 29 Overlord x2
- 36 Roaches

Cut Drones
Roaches all the way through.
This takes you up to the 6:30 Mark

- 2x Overlord
- 2x Extractor
- 56 Supply by this point.

That should pretty much cover the early roach aggression that could have been done. Everything else was reactionary to what he saw.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is getting the replay, but if that is not possible the only way I see is going through the video and noting down what he builds every time he spends resources, don't be afraid to pause and rewind when you see his resources go down, then note his food supply and what he build, personally I would use pen and paper but notepad would work also.

Remember that build order should only be what he starts out with making and not what he makes the whole game.